# React Native - local images in folder not resolving

Tags: react-native

When I do the following:

```
<Image source={require('./images/hex-loader2.gif')} style={{width:400,
height: 400}} />
```

I get the following error:

```
Unable to resolve module ./images/hex-loader2.gif from
/Applications/react/xxxx/views/LoginView.js: Invalid directory
/Applications/react/xxxx/views/images/hex-loader2.gif
```

Folder Structure is:

```
projectRoot > views > images
```

Any ideas why?

When I put the image at the same level of LoginView.js it works but as soon as I add it to the images folder I get the above error.